# Video download from HTML + UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiwebview, download

In my new application i need to download video from different-different web sites, Say it is video downloader application. For this what i am planing is Searching html for .mp4 and .Flv url and then trying to downloading videos. There are many app already doing same

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/video-downloader-super-lite/id481701140?mt=8

What i am asking is, how can  we download video? Any code or link or something. how this application work ?  Any Help will really appreciate.

what i needed is when you open a page in UIWebview Say you open "www.youtube.com" and select a video to play then it ask to download. For download i need URL (Embeded url, Flv url, mpv url) so i can paas this to function. I need to know about That URL

Comment: hey you find anything for this solution you give me ans on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library, it's pretty simple. You can make an HTTP request and use its [`outputStream`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ) property to download the file to your device. Say you hook up a download button to a function `downloadVideoFromURL:withName:`

```
- (void)downloadVideoFromURL:(NSURL*)url withName:(NSString*)videoName
{
    //filepath to your app's documents directory
    NSString *appDocPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *videosPath = [appDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Videos"];
    NSString *filePath = [videosPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", videoName]];

    //check to make sure video hasn't been downloaded already
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        //file was already downloaded
    }

    //video wasn't downloaded, so continue
    else
    {

        //enable the network activity indicator
        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];

        //create a temporary filepath while downloading
        NSString *tmpPath = [videosPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-tmp.mp4", videoName]];

        //the outputStream property is the key to downloading the file
        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:tmpPath append:NO];

        //if operation is completed successfully, do following
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            //rename the downloaded video to its proper name
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:tmpPath toPath:filePath error:nil];

            //disable network activity indicator
            [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = NO;

            //optionally, post a notification to anyone listening that the download was successful
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadedVideo" object:nil];

        //if the operation fails, do the following:
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

            //delete the downloaded file (it is probably partially downloaded or corrupt)
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tmpPath error:nil];

            //disable network activity indicator
            [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = NO;
        }];

        //start the operation
        [operation start];

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony for quick response, it is helpful but what i needed is when you open a page in UIWebview Say you open "www.youtube.com" and select a video to play then it ask to download. For download i need URL (Embeded url, Flv url, mpv url) so i can paas this to function. I need to know about That URL

Comment: @Mangesh Vyas , did you find a solution for you problem? I have the same task in my app, and I'm searching for solution now.

Comment: No petr...i didn't yet.... Even ia m interested too.. What i found is hard code the web side and then search in html for video URL and then start downloading...... But what i am looking for is there any API or some hack for safari browser, because video play with web browser....

Comment: does any one found the solution.i am still searching for the answer and  as there are lots of applications in the market then there must be a way to do so.

Comment: IF you using UIWebView than follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to go for hacking , you you will get apple's private library, "webkit" , if you try to find the subviews of UIWebview, it might help you, i never tried it, but you can test with this logic.

Comment: @Mangesh, Did you find any solution for it? I am doing same thing now.