# Detect video is going to be played in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, media-player

I want something similar to this:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-download-ibolt-downloader/id481606548?mt=8

I want to detect there is any video in web page and want to download that stream into iphone device.

In console media players tells that it is setting the movie path to some URL. There must be a way to download stream and save in local device.

P.S: I know how to download a video file. I want it using online streaming or from sites which does not provide a download link.

P.S++: [Video download from HTML + UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319278/video-download-from-html-uiwebview) is not helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Naveed, Do you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The post is old but it might be worth to clear this

Those apps are probably using undocumented API. Apple doesn't accept private API when apps are submitted to the app store, however they might not be looking for usage of undocumented notifications

You can find more information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253111/get-notification-when-a-video-starts-or-stops-in-uiwebview)

Those apps show you the download button after you click video, and after the video starts. So probably they are listening for media playback notifications and get the url from MPMoviePlayer instance.

By the way, apple doesn't allow apps that download videos from youtube. There might be some apps on the app store that does that, but I recently got rejected because of this. It might not be worth the hassle, as most big video streaming websites don't want people downloading their videos and work hard to make sure that they don't.